# Algorithm that process the autocorrelation function for each frame in order to extract the pitch period during that frame

Tags: matlab

I have a speech signal divided into n frames. I have a for loop that loops through each frame and calculates the auto correlation. But I don't know how I can extract the pitch period of each frame. Is there a function I can use? The snippet of code I have is as follows:

```
for j = 0:n
    frame{j+1} = y1((frameLength*(j))+1 : frameLength*(j+1));
       for i = minimumLag:maximumLag
        Autocorrelation(i) = autoCorrelate(frameLength,i,frames{j+1});
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

See reference
[link](http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=59&brch=164&sim=1012&cnt=1)
Looks like you just do a simple peak search on the resultant sequence. The reference suggests the 2nd strongest peak.